# How to upload a video to Google Cloud Storage? (Angularjs / ionic framework)

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, google-cloud-storage

I'm developing an app to let people upload short videos (8secs) to show products, the problem is I can't figure out how to upload a captured cordova file to GCS.

I'm using the cordova file transfer plugin and I created the iOS API key with the bundle identified of my app, but I still can't upload the video.

My code

```
'use strict';

app.controller('VideoCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaCapture, $state, FURL, Videos) {

$scope.videos = Videos;


$scope.record = function(){
  var options = { limit: 1, duration: 8 };
  $cordovaCapture.captureVideo(options).then(
      function(videoData) {
          var i, path, len;
          var pathtogo;
          var pathtogostring;
          for (i = 0, len = videoData.length; i < len; i += 1) {
              path = videoData[i].fullPath;
              pathtogo = path.toString();
              $scope.videos.$add(pathtogo);
            };
      },
      $state.go('tab.photo-detail'),

      function(err) {
      }
  );
$cordovaFileTransfer.upload("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/'mybucket'/o?uploadType=media", videoData[i].fullPath, {mimeType: "video/mov", fileName:"capturedvideo.MOV"}, true)
.then(function(result) {
            console.log("SUCCESS: " + JSON.stringify(result.response));
        }, function(err) {
            console.log("ERROR: " + JSON.stringify(err));
        }, function (progress) {
            // constant progress updates
        });
};

});
```

Thanks.